# While using Harbor create 'New Registry Endpoint' unhealthy issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, harbor

While using harbor create 'New Registry Endpoint' unhealthy issue as below:

I followed the https cert generation instruction as link: https://goharbor.io/docs/1.10/install-config/configure-https/

Harbor installed successfully, and logged in to create the 'New Registry Endpoint', and showed the issue `'registry https://hub.csp.cn is unhealthy: unhealthy'`

[the issue image as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWLxk.png)

I checked the harbor logs warning

`'Jun 25 09:40:26 172.18.0.1 core[1034]: 2020-06-25T01:40:26Z [ERROR] [/replication/adapter/native/adapter.go:154]: failed to ping registry https://hub.csp.cn: Head https://hub.csp.cn/v2/: Get https://hub.csp.cn/v2/: dial tcp: lookup hub.csp.cn on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host'`

The vmware IP is '192.168.111.100' and domain mapping is 'hub.csp.cn'

I followed the issue log to check the source as below:
[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHnHF.png)

I'm not familiar with the Go source code.

Does anyone have any idea about the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I config /harbor/common/config/core/env http=http://hub.csp.cn and https as https://hub.csp.cn,and also do the same config in /harbor/common/config/jobservice/env,and do the operation as below:
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up -d
The issue can't be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but thought I might be able to help someone else.

I had this happen using Terraform to add a dockerhub registry to Harbor. It was actually dockerhub telling me it didn't like my credentials. I hard-coded them to test and it worked.

Pretty sure I just needed to add double quotes around my token (which was an environment variable) instead of single quotes... That seems to be what fixed it.